# How to bind the value for 'data-target' in angular 5

Tags: angular

I have button with data-target. I want the data-target to be conditional where based on the condition (Boolean) the value for the data-target should be changed.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<button class='pricing-addon' style="margin-left: 20px"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add-addons">Add Add-on's</button>
```

i tried with **data-target = {{variable}}** it is not working even with
**[attr.data-target]="'#exampleModalCenter"**

is there any other way to bind the value conditionally in angular way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
[attr.data-target]="condition ? "true_option" : "false_option"
```

This will evaluate the condition, and depending on whether it's true or false, will set the value of data-target to the given option.

Comment: I Am getting the console error **Can't bind to 'data-target' since it isn't a known property of 'button'**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question.

**data-target** is used as method to trigger another element. 
You can use a simple click event and add a method to determine the value to be set and use *ngIf instead of using this attribute like this -

```
<button (click)="setValue($event)">
```

and inside **setValue** method you can determine the value to be set

`<element *ngIf="!value"></element>`

This is an alternative to achieve data-target feature.

Comment: it is working fine with [attr.data-target]="condition ? "true_option" : "false_option"

Comment: Great, this was just an alternative